# Site in desktop very good, but in mobile very small

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I'm making a website for dissemination with a logo, one spritezinho and a small text with a message.

When you access it from the desktop, resolution, size, alignment, all OK! But when accessing the cell, everything went extremely small size. How to solve it?

Website (If possible, access the cell to understand):

http://agoravai2.esy.es/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag to your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can read about what it does and the options it provides here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

You're missing [the viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in the `<head>`:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```